# Check, if value exists in response. eBay API

Tags: c#, xml, soap, nullreferenceexception

I have a problem with the development of an application.
I am using the eBay API to get information about the items a seller has listed. The Call I use is named "GetSellerList".

The response might contain a value called "CategoryID" (FreeAddedCategory.CategoryID) if there is a FreeAddedCategory available for the item. You would find a XML like this as response:

```
<ItemArray>
  <Item>
    <FreeAddedCategory>
      <CategoryID>XXXXXXXXX</CategoryID>
    </FreeAddedCategory>
  </Item>
</ItemArray>
```

Because this value is not always returned I am getting the following error message:

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

I now want to check if this object is available before using it to prevent getting the error. This is how I startet to solve the issue (but without success):

```
    foreach (ItemType item in apiCall.ApiResponse.ItemArray)
       {
          if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.FreeAddedCategory.CategoryID))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FreeAdded: Nicht vorhanden!");
                }
        }
```

But also this check brings up the same error message. What can I do to make the code working? The logic should be like that:

```
IF item.FreeAddedCategory.CategoryID exist
  {
      do everything that needs to be done
  }
ELSE skip;
```

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Issue is solved. I wrote my solution as a comment below Chuck's answer. And yes, it was a stupid beginners mistake ;) Sorry

Comment: @Filz 6 years later and your comment helped me fix my own issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // .Parse(string);
if (root.Descendants("FreeAddedCategory").Any())
{
   // do exists
}
else
{
   // doesn't exist
}
```

Or use `CategoryId` if that makes more sense for your case.

Comment: Hey Chuck, Thanks for you quick reply. My mistake was really stupid! Instead of checking "item.FreeAddedCategory.CategoryID" for "null" I had to check just "item.FreeAddedCategory". Because "item.FreeAddedCategory" had been "null" I did get the NullReferenceException when I tried to access "item.FreeAddedCategory.CategoryID".